# Revert back to an old version of Lua?

Tags: lua, version, revert

I just recently installed Lua 5.3 on my system and am running into compatibility errors. I'd like to set my 'installed' Lua preference to go back to lua 5.1 or 5.2, even if I have to delete 5.3 completely.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua 5.3 builds by default with compatibility with Lua 5.2.

If you aren't using the Makefile from lua.org, make sure to build Lua 5.3 with `LUA_COMPAT_5_2` defined.

If you want to revert to Lua 5.2, just uninstall Lua 5.3 (`make uninstall`) and install whatever version you want.

Comment: `make uninstall` inside the lua-5.3 from lua.org, put me back on 5.2.